# Set background-image ID using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have different backgrounds based on the users device size.  I have set the background-image using JQuery, no problem there.  Now I need to set the background-image's ID, and I can't seem to figure it out.
I need the ID set to bg for another script down below.

Please Help!

Thanks

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("body");
 if (screen.width <= 1300) {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(images/jpg/SmallLeather.jpg)');}
else{
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(images/jpg/BackGroundCon.jpg)');
    $('body').css('background-image', 'id (bg)');}
</script>  
<script>
$(window).load(function() {    
    var theWindow        = $(window),
    $bg              = $("#bg"),
    aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();
function resizeBg() {
    if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
        $bg
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('bgheight');
    } else {
        $bg
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('bgwidth');
    }
}
theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");
});
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to make your life slightly easier using [CSS media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: To all you out there with the quick responses, THANKS! It's way to late for me, forgot there was no id for BG image!  I had gotten off on a tangent when I grabbed the JQuery line.  The correct answer was to use and image, not the background image property, like so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A background image doesn't have it's own id.  The object for which it is set as a background can have the id.  You can then get to the background image by finding the host object with that id and then setting the background image on that object.

If the object in question is the body, then you don't really need an id to retrieve that object since you can refer to it as `document.body` at any time.  There is built-in access to that object in javascript.

Also, you may be able to dynamically adjust the background image based on window size entirely with CSS (no javascript) by using [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

Use **[attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to set the `id` attribute of the body to `bg`.

`$('body').attr('id', 'bg');`

Comment: Why would one ever need to do this when you can just refer to the body object at any time as `document.body`.

Comment: True. But if you check his current code he is having trouble with his selector `$("#bg")`.

Comment: Honestly, I can't follow what in the heck the OP is trying to do in his code.  I just tried to respond to the words of the question.

Comment: I think he only want to execute the lower script when the screen size is > 1300

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the background-image id, since it doesn't have one. I would recommend use `.addClass()` to add in the needed id (now is a class), or if the body doesn't have an id yet, use `.attr("id", "bg")` to set the id for the body tag. And then get the background-image through `.css("background-image")`.

Update: seems that u want to resize the background-image. If you are, consider using `background-size: cover` or `contain` in the css. While you're at it, use media queries mentioned in one of the answer too

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $('body').attr('id');
$("#"+id).css('background-image', 'url(BackGroundCon.jpg)');
```

Comment: What will this accomplish beyond `$(document.body).css('background-image', 'url(BackGroundCon.jpg)');`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with....

```
<img src="images/jpg/BackGroundCon.jpg" id="bg" alt=""> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var theDiv = document.getElementById("body");
if (screen.width <= 1300) {
var img= 'images/jpg/SmallLeather.jpg';
$('#bg').attr("src",img); 
 }

</script><script>
$(window).load(function() {    
var theWindow        = $(window),
    $bg              = $("#bg"),
    aspectRatio      = $bg.width() / $bg.height();
function resizeBg() {
    if ( (theWindow.width() / theWindow.height()) < aspectRatio ) {
        $bg
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('bgheight');
    } else {
        $bg
            .removeClass()
            .addClass('bgwidth');
    }
}
theWindow.resize(resizeBg).trigger("resize");
});
</script>
```

Here it is in action, at least for the time being.
http://heretomeet.com

StackExchange will not allow me to accept more than one of your responses, which is a shame as so many of you had really helpful comments at 2:00 am!  When do you people sleep?

Thanks

Don